# Qt QWidget hide animation

Tags: c++, qt, animation, qwidget

I have a sub-class of `QWidget` that is a popup widget. I would like to add some animation when it shows and disappears. So I re-implemented `showEvent(QShowEvent * event)` and `hideEvent` and added some `QPropertyAnimation` in the functions. The `showEvent` works just fine for me but the `hideEvent` doesn't. Because

> Hide events are sent to widgets immediately after they have been hidden.

Any idea about how to do it?

Update:

I don't think it's the right reason. When I use Nejat's solution. The show part works. But when I click outside the widget. It disappears immediately.

Answer (score 2):

You should override `QWidget::closeEvent()` so when trying to close immediatly it will be ignored AND we start our animation and after finishing (`QPropertyAnimation::finished()`) we close the widget as normal.

Here is a demo to demonstrate:

```
class AnimatedWidget : public QWidget {
    Q_OBJECT
        Q_PROPERTY(qreal alpha READ alpha WRITE setAlpha)

public:
    AnimatedWidget(QWidget* parent = nullptr) :QWidget{ parent }, opacityAnimation{ new QPropertyAnimation{this, "alpha",this} } {
        setWindowFlags(windowFlags() | Qt::WindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint) | Qt::Tool);
        auto pal = palette();
        pal.setColor(QPalette::Background, Qt::cyan);
        setAutoFillBackground(true);
        setPalette(pal);
        setFixedSize(200, 200);
    }

    qreal alpha() const {
        return windowOpacity();
    }

    void setAlpha(qreal level) {
        setWindowOpacity(level);
        update();
    }

protected:
    void closeEvent(QCloseEvent* e) override {
        if (opacityAnimation->currentValue().toReal() == 1.0) { // Ignore event + start animation
            e->ignore();
            startHide();
            QObject::connect(opacityAnimation, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(onAnimationCallBack()), Qt::UniqueConnection);
        } else {
            e->accept();
            if (!isHidden())
                hide();
            QWidget::close(); // necessary actions
        }
    }

    public Q_SLOTS:
    void show() {
        startShow();
        QWidget::show(); // necessary actions
    }

    private Q_SLOTS:
    void onAnimationCallBack() {
        if (opacityAnimation->currentValue().toReal() == 0.0) { // we're finished so let's really close the widget
            QCloseEvent ev;
            QApplication::sendEvent(this, &ev);
            qApp->sendEvent(this, &ev);
        }
    }

    void startHide() {
        opacityAnimation->setStartValue(1.0);
        opacityAnimation->setEndValue(0.0);
        opacityAnimation->setDuration(1500);
        opacityAnimation->start();
    }

    void startShow() {
        opacityAnimation->setStartValue(0.0);
        opacityAnimation->setEndValue(1.0);
        opacityAnimation->setDuration(1500);
        opacityAnimation->start();
    }

private:
    QPropertyAnimation* opacityAnimation = nullptr;
};

class Base : public QWidget {
public:
    Base(QWidget* parent = nullptr) :QWidget{ parent }, widget{ new AnimatedWidget{} } {

    }

private:
    AnimatedWidget* widget;

protected:
    void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent* e) override {
        if (widget->isHidden())
            widget->show();
        else
            widget->close();
        QWidget::mouseReleaseEvent(e);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    Base base;
    base.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

[image]

Comment: Ty for the answer. But it has been a long time. I can't test it now. I'll mark it as the accepted answer if you get some upvote so that it can help others who has the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can override the `eventFilter` in your widget and check for `QEvent::Show` and `QEvent::Close` events.

```
bool MyWidget::eventFilter(QObject * obj, QEvent * event)
{
    if(obj == this && event->type() == QEvent::Show)
    {
        //about to show
    }
    else if(obj == this && event->type() == QEvent::Close)
    {
        //about to close
    }


    return false;
}
```

You should also install the event filter in the constructor by:

```
this->installEventFilter(this);
```

Comment: It doesn't work well. The show part works without problem. Maybe I got the wrong reason. When I click outside the widget. It disappears immediately.